# c++ eclipse library inclusion

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, include, eclipse-cdt

I'm following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) tutorial and gotten to the part where I have to import the libraries. 
I used the command line to find where the files where located:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/usr/include/opencv2
```

and the second command:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

Using search I was able to determine that these files existed in /usr/lib. So I added that to the location of the libaries in the GCC linker.

Click [here](http://s24.postimg.org/pn9gn06np/problem.png) to see the GCC linker.
And [here](http://s8.postimg.org/72g3dxerp/Screenshot_from_2014_02_27_12_05_32.png) for the compiler includes

However there are still problems that appear to come from not properly including the library ( `#include <cv.h>` cannot be found for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, turns out that in the version of openCV I was using the highgui is placed in `<highgui/highgui>` just `<highgui>` addionally I should have used `<opencv.hpp>` instead of `<opencv.h>`.
So it was a version difference between opencv and the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Eclipse user, but I'll give it a try.

What you've done is include the directories from where libraries will be LINKED. See in your picture the "Library search path (-L)". You set the -L option. But you still need to tell the compiler where to read the header files (*.h) from (the -I option). By looking at your picture, I'm guessing you may set that option in the section "GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes". (If you're writing C code, then: "GCC C compiler -> includes"

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have also included a picture of the compiler includes now. Does that look all right to you?

Comment: Yeah, I think that should've done. If it's still not working you cant try to include the same path to the "GCC C Compiler -> Includes".

Comment: Not really. Are you sure the files are in that path? Could you post the command line generated by Eclipse to compile a file?